# How to apache logs in this format?

Tags: html, css, web, logging

I am using a plain HTML file and try to show the apache logs using labels. But all lines are getting truncated and showing as a paragraph. Is any way in which I can show that logs on their original format on the web page.
The log that I need to display:-

```
Execution of 3 spec files started at 2020-08-11T10:45:13.392Z

Starting ChromeDriver 83.0.4103.39 (ccbf011cb2d2b19b506d844400483861342c20cd-refs/branch-heads/4103@{#416}) on port 9515
Only local connections are allowed.
Please see https://chromedriver.chromium.org/security-considerations for suggestions on keeping ChromeDriver safe.
ChromeDriver was started successfully.
[0-0] RUNNING in chrome - /1_features/sample1.feature
[0-0] wdio testing--> something
[0-0] https://webdriver.io/docs/api/browser/waitUntil.html
[0-0] (//descendant::*[contains(text(),"Blog")])[1]
[0-0] (//descendant::*[contains(text(),"Versions")])[1]
[0-0] PASSED in chrome - /1_features/sample1.feature
[0-1] RUNNING in chrome - /1_features/t - Copy.feature
[0-1] wdio testing--> something
[0-1] Error in "Login Validation: Visit Websites: Given I print consoles "something""
Step "Given I print consoles "something"" is not definedYou can ignore this error by setting cucumberOpts.ignoreUndefinedDefinitions as true.
[0-1] wdio testing--> something
[0-1] wdio testing--> something2
[0-1] wdio testing--> something
[0-1] Error in "Login Validation: Visit Websites: Given I print consoles "something""
Step "Given I print consoles "something"" is not definedYou can ignore this error by setting cucumberOpts.ignoreUndefinedDefinitions as true.
[0-1] FAILED in chrome - /1_features/t - Copy.feature
[0-2] RUNNING in chrome - /1_features/t.feature
[0-2] wdio testing--> something
[0-2] PASSED in chrome - /1_features/t.feature

 Cucumber HTML report 3_reports/testReport.html generated successfully 

 "spec" Reporter:
------------------------------------------------------------------
[chrome 83.0.4103.116 linux #0-0] Spec: /home/cloud-user/bdd/1_features/sample1.feature
[chrome 83.0.4103.116 linux #0-0] Running: chrome (v83.0.4103.116) on linux
[chrome 83.0.4103.116 linux #0-0] Session ID: 5f4519cdbf15a61efaef92bc53bb31a7
[chrome 83.0.4103.116 linux #0-0]
[chrome 83.0.4103.116 linux #0-0] Login Validation
[chrome 83.0.4103.116 linux #0-0]     Visit Websites Once
[chrome 83.0.4103.116 linux #0-0]        ✓ Given I print console "something"
[chrome 83.0.4103.116 linux #0-0]        ✓ Given I open the url "https://webdriver.io/docs/api/browser/waitUntil.html"
[chrome 83.0.4103.116 linux #0-0]        ✓ When I click on "Blog"
[chrome 83.0.4103.116 linux #0-0]        ✓ And I wait for a while
[chrome 83.0.4103.116 linux #0-0]        ✓ When I click on "Versions"
[chrome 83.0.4103.116 linux #0-0]        ✓ Given the following verifications:
[chrome 83.0.4103.116 linux #0-0]          │ Help │
[chrome 83.0.4103.116 linux #0-0]          │ Blog │
[chrome 83.0.4103.116 linux #0-0]        ✓ Then I verify if "Contribute" exists
[chrome 83.0.4103.116 linux #0-0]        ✓ And I wait for a while
[chrome 83.0.4103.116 linux #0-0]
[chrome 83.0.4103.116 linux #0-0] 8 passing (9.9s)
------------------------------------------------------------------
[chrome 83.0.4103.116 linux #0-1] Spec: /home/cloud-user/bdd/1_features/t - Copy.feature
[chrome 83.0.4103.116 linux #0-1] Running: chrome (v83.0.4103.116) on linux
[chrome 83.0.4103.116 linux #0-1] Session ID: b62a9cda00fee2ce7e93bd8cc2e6b1e6
[chrome 83.0.4103.116 linux #0-1]
[chrome 83.0.4103.116 linux #0-1] Login Validation
[chrome 83.0.4103.116 linux #0-1]     Visit Websites
[chrome 83.0.4103.116 linux #0-1]        ✓ Given I print console "something"
[chrome 83.0.4103.116 linux #0-1]        ✖ Given I print consoles "something"
[chrome 83.0.4103.116 linux #0-1]        - Given I print console "minister"
[chrome 83.0.4103.116 linux #0-1]
[chrome 83.0.4103.116 linux #0-1]     Visit Websites
[chrome 83.0.4103.116 linux #0-1]        ✓ Given I print console "something"
[chrome 83.0.4103.116 linux #0-1]
[chrome 83.0.4103.116 linux #0-1]     Visit Websites
[chrome 83.0.4103.116 linux #0-1]        ✓ Given I print console "something2"
[chrome 83.0.4103.116 linux #0-1]
[chrome 83.0.4103.116 linux #0-1]     Visit Websites
[chrome 83.0.4103.116 linux #0-1]        ✓ Given I print console "something"
[chrome 83.0.4103.116 linux #0-1]        ✖ Given I print consoles "something"
[chrome 83.0.4103.116 linux #0-1]        - Given I print console "minister"
[chrome 83.0.4103.116 linux #0-1]
[chrome 83.0.4103.116 linux #0-1] 4 passing (1.2s)
[chrome 83.0.4103.116 linux #0-1] 2 failing
[chrome 83.0.4103.116 linux #0-1] 2 skipped
[chrome 83.0.4103.116 linux #0-1]
[chrome 83.0.4103.116 linux #0-1] 1) Visit Websites Given I print consoles "something"
[chrome 83.0.4103.116 linux #0-1] Step "Given I print consoles "something"" is not definedYou can ignore this error by setting cucumberOpts.ignoreUndefinedDefinitions as true.
[chrome 83.0.4103.116 linux #0-1] undefined:undefined
[chrome 83.0.4103.116 linux #0-1]
[chrome 83.0.4103.116 linux #0-1] 2) Visit Websites Given I print consoles "something"
[chrome 83.0.4103.116 linux #0-1] Step "Given I print consoles "something"" is not definedYou can ignore this error by setting cucumberOpts.ignoreUndefinedDefinitions as true.
[chrome 83.0.4103.116 linux #0-1] undefined:undefined
------------------------------------------------------------------
[chrome 83.0.4103.116 linux #0-2] Spec: /home/cloud-user/bdd/1_features/t.feature
[chrome 83.0.4103.116 linux #0-2] Running: chrome (v83.0.4103.116) on linux
[chrome 83.0.4103.116 linux #0-2] Session ID: a755f0dfa3599d3fc41a29f02f95758d
[chrome 83.0.4103.116 linux #0-2]
[chrome 83.0.4103.116 linux #0-2] Login Validation
[chrome 83.0.4103.116 linux #0-2]     Visit Websites
[chrome 83.0.4103.116 linux #0-2]        ✓ Given I print console "something"
[chrome 83.0.4103.116 linux #0-2]
[chrome 83.0.4103.116 linux #0-2] 1 passing (448ms)


Spec Files:  2 passed, 1 failed, 3 total (100% completed) in 00:00:15
```

But currently displaying like :

> Execution of 3 spec files started at 2020-08-11T10:45:13.392Z
>
> Starting ChromeDriver 83.0.4103.39
> (ccbf011cb2d2b19b506d844400483861342c20cd-refs/branch-heads/4103@{#416})
> on port 9515 Only local connections are allowed. Please see
> https://chromedriver.chromium.org/security-considerations for
> suggestions on keeping ChromeDriver safe. ChromeDriver was started
> successfully. [0-0] RUNNING in chrome - /1_features/sample1.feature
> [0-0] wdio testing--> something [0-0]
> https://webdriver.io/docs/api/browser/waitUntil.html [0-0]
> (//descendant::*[contains(text(),"Blog")])[1] [0-0]
> (//descendant::*[contains(text(),"Versions")])[1] [0-0] PASSED in
> chrome - /1_features/sample1.feature [0-1] RUNNING in chrome -
> /1_features/t - Copy.feature [0-1] wdio testing--> something [0-1]
> Error in "Login Validation: Visit Websites: Given I print consoles
> "something"" Step "Given I print consoles "something"" is not
> definedYou can ignore this error by setting
> cucumberOpts.ignoreUndefinedDefinitions as true. [0-1] wdio testing-->
> something [0-1] wdio testing--> something2 [0-1] wdio testing-->
> something [0-1] Error in "Login Validation: Visit Websites: Given I
> print consoles "something"" Step "Given I print consoles "something""
> is not definedYou can ignore this error by setting
> cucumberOpts.ignoreUndefinedDefinitions as true. [0-1] FAILED in
> chrome - /1_features/t - Copy.feature [0-2] RUNNING in chrome -
> /1_features/t.feature [0-2] wdio testing--> something [0-2] PASSED in
> chrome - /1_features/t.feature
>
> Cucumber HTML report 3_reports/testReport.html generated
> successfully
>
> "spec" Reporter:
> ------------------------------------------------------------------ [chrome 83.0.4103.116 linux #0-0] Spec:
> /home/cloud-user/bdd/1_features/sample1.feature [chrome 83.0.4103.116
> linux #0-0] Running: chrome (v83.0.4103.116) on linux [chrome
> 83.0.4103.116 linux #0-0] Session ID: 5f4519cdbf15a61efaef92bc53bb31a7 [chrome 83.0.4103.116 linux #0-0] [chrome 83.0.4103.116 linux #0-0]
> Login Validation [chrome 83.0.4103.116 linux #0-0]     Visit Websites
> Once [chrome 83.0.4103.116 linux #0-0]        ✓ Given I print console
> "something" [chrome 83.0.4103.116 linux #0-0]        ✓ Given I open
> the url "https://webdriver.io/docs/api/browser/waitUntil.html" [chrome
> 83.0.4103.116 linux #0-0]        ✓ When I click on "Blog" [chrome 83.0.4103.116 linux #0-0]        ✓ And I wait for a while [chrome 83.0.4103.116 linux #0-0]        ✓ When I click on "Versions" [chrome 83.0.4103.116 linux #0-0]        ✓ Given the following verifications: [chrome 83.0.4103.116 linux #0-0]          │ Help │ [chrome
> 83.0.4103.116 linux #0-0]          │ Blog │ [chrome 83.0.4103.116 linux #0-0]        ✓ Then I verify if "Contribute" exists [chrome
> 83.0.4103.116 linux #0-0]        ✓ And I wait for a while [chrome 83.0.4103.116 linux #0-0] [chrome 83.0.4103.116 linux #0-0] 8 passing (9.9s)
> ------------------------------------------------------------------ [chrome 83.0.4103.116 linux #0-1] Spec:
> /home/cloud-user/bdd/1_features/t - Copy.feature [chrome 83.0.4103.116
> linux #0-1] Running: chrome (v83.0.4103.116) on linux [chrome
> 83.0.4103.116 linux #0-1] Session ID: b62a9cda00fee2ce7e93bd8cc2e6b1e6 [chrome 83.0.4103.116 linux #0-1] [chrome 83.0.4103.116 linux #0-1]
> Login Validation [chrome 83.0.4103.116 linux #0-1]     Visit Websites
> [chrome 83.0.4103.116 linux #0-1]        ✓ Given I print console
> "something" [chrome 83.0.4103.116 linux #0-1]        ✖ Given I print
> consoles "something" [chrome 83.0.4103.116 linux #0-1]        - Given
> I print console "minister" [chrome 83.0.4103.116 linux #0-1] [chrome
> 83.0.4103.116 linux #0-1]     Visit Websites [chrome 83.0.4103.116 linux #0-1]        ✓ Given I print console "something" [chrome
> 83.0.4103.116 linux #0-1] [chrome 83.0.4103.116 linux #0-1]     Visit Websites [chrome 83.0.4103.116 linux #0-1]        ✓ Given I print
> console "something2" [chrome 83.0.4103.116 linux #0-1] [chrome
> 83.0.4103.116 linux #0-1]     Visit Websites [chrome 83.0.4103.116 linux #0-1]        ✓ Given I print console "something" [chrome
> 83.0.4103.116 linux #0-1]        ✖ Given I print consoles "something" [chrome 83.0.4103.116 linux #0-1]        - Given I print console
> "minister" [chrome 83.0.4103.116 linux #0-1] [chrome 83.0.4103.116
> linux #0-1] 4 passing (1.2s) [chrome 83.0.4103.116 linux #0-1] 2
> failing [chrome 83.0.4103.116 linux #0-1] 2 skipped [chrome
> 83.0.4103.116 linux #0-1] [chrome 83.0.4103.116 linux #0-1] 1) Visit Websites Given I print consoles "something" [chrome 83.0.4103.116
> linux #0-1] Step "Given I print consoles "something"" is not
> definedYou can ignore this error by setting
> cucumberOpts.ignoreUndefinedDefinitions as true. [chrome 83.0.4103.116
> linux #0-1] undefined:undefined [chrome 83.0.4103.116 linux #0-1]
> [chrome 83.0.4103.116 linux #0-1] 2) Visit Websites Given I print
> consoles "something" [chrome 83.0.4103.116 linux #0-1] Step "Given I
> print consoles "something"" is not definedYou can ignore this error by
> setting cucumberOpts.ignoreUndefinedDefinitions as true. [chrome
> 83.0.4103.116 linux #0-1] undefined:undefined
> ------------------------------------------------------------------ [chrome 83.0.4103.116 linux #0-2] Spec:
> /home/cloud-user/bdd/1_features/t.feature [chrome 83.0.4103.116 linux
> #0-2] Running: chrome (v83.0.4103.116) on linux [chrome 83.0.4103.116 linux #0-2] Session ID: a755f0dfa3599d3fc41a29f02f95758d [chrome
> 83.0.4103.116 linux #0-2] [chrome 83.0.4103.116 linux #0-2] Login Validation [chrome 83.0.4103.116 linux #0-2]     Visit Websites
> [chrome 83.0.4103.116 linux #0-2]        ✓ Given I print console
> "something" [chrome 83.0.4103.116 linux #0-2] [chrome 83.0.4103.116
> linux #0-2] 1 passing (448ms)
>
> Spec Files:    2 passed, 1 failed, 3 total (100% completed) in 00:00:15

The code that I am trying is:-

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>log display</title>
    </head>
<body>
    <code>
    Execution of 3 spec files started at 2020-08-11T10:45:13.392Z

Starting ChromeDriver 83.0.4103.39 (ccbf011cb2d2b19b506d844400483861342c20cd-refs/branch-heads/4103@{#416}) on port 9515
Only local connections are allowed.
Please see https://chromedriver.chromium.org/security-considerations for suggestions on keeping ChromeDriver safe.
ChromeDriver was started successfully.
[0-0] RUNNING in chrome - /1_features/sample1.feature
[0-0] wdio testing--> something
[0-0] https://webdriver.io/docs/api/browser/waitUntil.html
[0-0] (//descendant::*[contains(text(),"Blog")])[1]
[0-0] (//descendant::*[contains(text(),"Versions")])[1]
[0-0] PASSED in chrome - /1_features/sample1.feature
[0-1] RUNNING in chrome - /1_features/t - Copy.feature
[0-1] wdio testing--> something
[0-1] Error in "Login Validation: Visit Websites: Given I print consoles "something""
Step "Given I print consoles "something"" is not definedYou can ignore this error by setting cucumberOpts.ignoreUndefinedDefinitions as true.
[0-1] wdio testing--> something
[0-1] wdio testing--> something2
[0-1] wdio testing--> something
[0-1] Error in "Login Validation: Visit Websites: Given I print consoles "something""
Step "Given I print consoles "something"" is not definedYou can ignore this error by setting cucumberOpts.ignoreUndefinedDefinitions as true.
[0-1] FAILED in chrome - /1_features/t - Copy.feature
[0-2] RUNNING in chrome - /1_features/t.feature
[0-2] wdio testing--> something
[0-2] PASSED in chrome - /1_features/t.feature

 Cucumber HTML report 3_reports/testReport.html generated successfully 

 "spec" Reporter:
------------------------------------------------------------------
[chrome 83.0.4103.116 linux #0-0] Spec: /home/cloud-user/bdd/1_features/sample1.feature
[chrome 83.0.4103.116 linux #0-0] Running: chrome (v83.0.4103.116) on linux
[chrome 83.0.4103.116 linux #0-0] Session ID: 5f4519cdbf15a61efaef92bc53bb31a7
[chrome 83.0.4103.116 linux #0-0]
[chrome 83.0.4103.116 linux #0-0] Login Validation
[chrome 83.0.4103.116 linux #0-0]     Visit Websites Once
[chrome 83.0.4103.116 linux #0-0]        ✓ Given I print console "something"
[chrome 83.0.4103.116 linux #0-0]        ✓ Given I open the url "https://webdriver.io/docs/api/browser/waitUntil.html"
[chrome 83.0.4103.116 linux #0-0]        ✓ When I click on "Blog"
[chrome 83.0.4103.116 linux #0-0]        ✓ And I wait for a while
[chrome 83.0.4103.116 linux #0-0]        ✓ When I click on "Versions"
[chrome 83.0.4103.116 linux #0-0]        ✓ Given the following verifications:
[chrome 83.0.4103.116 linux #0-0]          │ Help │
[chrome 83.0.4103.116 linux #0-0]          │ Blog │
[chrome 83.0.4103.116 linux #0-0]        ✓ Then I verify if "Contribute" exists
[chrome 83.0.4103.116 linux #0-0]        ✓ And I wait for a while
[chrome 83.0.4103.116 linux #0-0]
[chrome 83.0.4103.116 linux #0-0] 8 passing (9.9s)
------------------------------------------------------------------
[chrome 83.0.4103.116 linux #0-1] Spec: /home/cloud-user/bdd/1_features/t - Copy.feature
[chrome 83.0.4103.116 linux #0-1] Running: chrome (v83.0.4103.116) on linux
[chrome 83.0.4103.116 linux #0-1] Session ID: b62a9cda00fee2ce7e93bd8cc2e6b1e6
[chrome 83.0.4103.116 linux #0-1]
[chrome 83.0.4103.116 linux #0-1] Login Validation
[chrome 83.0.4103.116 linux #0-1]     Visit Websites
[chrome 83.0.4103.116 linux #0-1]        ✓ Given I print console "something"
[chrome 83.0.4103.116 linux #0-1]        ✖ Given I print consoles "something"
[chrome 83.0.4103.116 linux #0-1]        - Given I print console "minister"
[chrome 83.0.4103.116 linux #0-1]
[chrome 83.0.4103.116 linux #0-1]     Visit Websites
[chrome 83.0.4103.116 linux #0-1]        ✓ Given I print console "something"
[chrome 83.0.4103.116 linux #0-1]
[chrome 83.0.4103.116 linux #0-1]     Visit Websites
[chrome 83.0.4103.116 linux #0-1]        ✓ Given I print console "something2"
[chrome 83.0.4103.116 linux #0-1]
[chrome 83.0.4103.116 linux #0-1]     Visit Websites
[chrome 83.0.4103.116 linux #0-1]        ✓ Given I print console "something"
[chrome 83.0.4103.116 linux #0-1]        ✖ Given I print consoles "something"
[chrome 83.0.4103.116 linux #0-1]        - Given I print console "minister"
[chrome 83.0.4103.116 linux #0-1]
[chrome 83.0.4103.116 linux #0-1] 4 passing (1.2s)
[chrome 83.0.4103.116 linux #0-1] 2 failing
[chrome 83.0.4103.116 linux #0-1] 2 skipped
[chrome 83.0.4103.116 linux #0-1]
[chrome 83.0.4103.116 linux #0-1] 1) Visit Websites Given I print consoles "something"
[chrome 83.0.4103.116 linux #0-1] Step "Given I print consoles "something"" is not definedYou can ignore this error by setting cucumberOpts.ignoreUndefinedDefinitions as true.
[chrome 83.0.4103.116 linux #0-1] undefined:undefined
[chrome 83.0.4103.116 linux #0-1]
[chrome 83.0.4103.116 linux #0-1] 2) Visit Websites Given I print consoles "something"
[chrome 83.0.4103.116 linux #0-1] Step "Given I print consoles "something"" is not definedYou can ignore this error by setting cucumberOpts.ignoreUndefinedDefinitions as true.
[chrome 83.0.4103.116 linux #0-1] undefined:undefined
------------------------------------------------------------------
[chrome 83.0.4103.116 linux #0-2] Spec: /home/cloud-user/bdd/1_features/t.feature
[chrome 83.0.4103.116 linux #0-2] Running: chrome (v83.0.4103.116) on linux
[chrome 83.0.4103.116 linux #0-2] Session ID: a755f0dfa3599d3fc41a29f02f95758d
[chrome 83.0.4103.116 linux #0-2]
[chrome 83.0.4103.116 linux #0-2] Login Validation
[chrome 83.0.4103.116 linux #0-2]     Visit Websites
[chrome 83.0.4103.116 linux #0-2]        ✓ Given I print console "something"
[chrome 83.0.4103.116 linux #0-2]
[chrome 83.0.4103.116 linux #0-2] 1 passing (448ms)


Spec Files:  2 passed, 1 failed, 3 total (100% completed) in 00:00:15 
</code>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sorry, the header of this question is like: How to show apache logs in this format?

Comment: Hi I am able to print it by putting it in the html <pre></pre> tag.